# Cancelling an existing WF instance

Tags: workflow-foundation

I have a workflow service that takes a product object and then puts that in a queue from where it has to be approved by a manager.  There is a possibility that the product could be resubmitted into this process and if this is the case I want to cancel the existing workflow (that is waiting for approval).  The product id is used for correlation.

In my workflow I had a receive activity which takes the product object and assigns it to a variable.  I then had a separate InitializeCorrelation activity which initializes using the product id from the variable.  The workflow then returns the product to the calling client.

If I send the same product to the service twice then on the second call the service would return a fault exception of type

```
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstanceKeyCollisionException
```

with an error message of...

```
"The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted by a key collision. The instance key with value 'fd923b75-003e-13d9-0c96-21ed171fdb43' could not be associated to the instance because it is already associated to a different instance."
```

...which is basically what I would expect.  My plan was to wrap the InitializeCorrelation  activity with a try/catch activity and in the catch I was going to cancel the existing WF instance and continue with running instance.  So the catch would have a custom activity to cancel the existing WF instance and another initializeCorrelation activity which shouldn't throw an error as the first instance has been cancelled at that point.

However stepping through the workflow what happens is that it gets to the InitializeCorrelation activity, but that activity doesn't seem to properly raise the exception.  The InitializeCorrelation activity aborts the running instance and never hits the catch block.

My question therefore is how can I either:

1. Catch the exception from the InitializeCorrelation activity?
2. Can I wrap the InitializeCorrelation in a CodeActivity (I have followed an example that does this, but when I try and use it it doesn't seem to properly note the correlation and allows me to pass the same product into multiple instances without a problem).  I am setting the correlation handle and data properly, but I can't see how the activities execute method can be called.
3. Before I call InitializeCorrelation can I query all existing instances for one with a correlation Id equal to my product id?

Or perhaps there is a better way to do this?  One thing I don't want to do is catch the exception at the client side and do it from there.  My clients shouldn't know anything about WF and I am keen for them to continue working with the service interface and not have to put any retry/cancel logic in the clients (and really it should be possible to contain all this within the workflow itself).

Any help appreciated!